# Fill broken parts of an image using Python, OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a Captcha image like this:[Captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt4bu.jpg)

And Im writing a program to read it. Before any ML work I want to fill the parts where the image is broken. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post the original image as well?

Comment: The accepted answer [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/opencv-c-connect-nearby-contours-based-on-distance-between-them) might be something you could try. This of course will require tuning for your specific problem. Basically you get the contours of the text you can see and join those that are close enough.

Comment: Fooling captcha isn't going to be easy... or feasible...

Comment: @JeruLuke the image is in the link 'captcha image' at https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt4bu.jpg thats one of many such images I want to fix before passing it to an ocr. For example in this one I want to fill the broken e's and r.